# How to reverse an __m128 type variable?

Tags: c++, c, x86, sse, simd

I know this should be a Googling question but I just cannot find the answer.

Say I have an `__m128` variable `a`, whose content is `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `a[3]`. Is there a *single* function that can reverse it to be `a[3]`, `a[2]`, `a[1]`, `a[0]`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [_mm_shuffle_ps()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/5f0858x0(v=vs.90)). This instruction was already available in SSE and can gather 4 32-bit components in a single vector by combining two arbitrary 32-bit components from each of the two input vectors.

**How to create the mask using the macro [`_MM_SHUFFLE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/4d3eabky(v=vs.90))**

The macro is defined as follows:

```
/* Create a selector for use with the SHUFPS instruction.  */
#define _MM_SHUFFLE(fp3,fp2,fp1,fp0) \
 (((fp3) << 6) | ((fp2) << 4) | ((fp1) << 2) | (fp0))
```

Source and destination indices run from right to left in ascending order.
The first two selector values (`fp0` and `fp1`) designate source components in `m1`,
the last two (`fp2` and `fp3`) the ones in `m2`. Each selected source component is assigned to `m3[index]`, where `index` corresponds to its selector parameter `fp<index>`.

[image]

**Reversing 32-bit components in a vector**

```
__m128 input = ...;
__m128 reversed = _mm_shuffle_ps(input,input,_MM_SHUFFLE(0, 1, 2, 3));
```

**Note:** The mask is an immediate value. It cannot be dynamic, as it is part of the resulting machine instruction.

Intel Intrinsics Guide: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/

Comment: N.B. To shuffle a single vector arbitrarily (instead of shuffling two different vectors together with some restrictions), the first two arguments to `_mm_shuffle_ps()` will be the same.

Comment: Your description of `_MM_SHUFFLE` is backwards -- the first two arguments are the words selected from the SECOND argument (with 0 being the LSW) and packed into the upper half of the result, while the last two args are the words selected from the FIRST argument.  Why is it swapped?  Who knows.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thank you for pointing that out. The description was wrong because it did not cover the parameter order. I tried to clarify that. I would argue that swapping the vector parameters of `_mm_shuffle_ps()` could make sense in terms of consistency in this particular case, but not necessarily in general.