# x86 XMM register bit relocation

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

The following should be done in x86 assembly (up to SSE4) language.
Lets say I have a 128 bit XMM register:

`xmm0: [d, c, b, a]`

And I want another register which look like this:

`xmm1: [-,-, c, d]`

For xmm1 the high 64 bits are not important. The ultimate goal is I want to have

`[-,-,b+c,a-d]`

I can do this then with `addsub`.
Is there any useful instructions up to SSE4 to do this efficiently? How can I do this at all?
My Idea is some shift operations but couldnt find any useful in the Intel Developer Manual.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56407741/11683?

Comment: what intrinsics have you tried so far?  you know what i mean by intrinsics .... or you don't?

Comment: My answer on your previous question, [Expand the lower two 32-bit floats of an xmm register to the whole xmm register](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65642003), shows how to get a compiler to come up wit ha shuffle for you, so you don't have to ask a separate question for every specific shuffle. It also points out the existence of `shufps` and `pshufd` which can do arbitrary dword shuffles.

Comment: `_mm_shuffle_epi32` , `_mm_cvtepu32_epi64` , `_mm_shuffle_epi32`

Comment: @PeterCordes it's not a duplicate really. i do not see code at all in link you'd posted. and this one has nothing to  do with zero-extend

Comment: https://github.com/alexeyneu/BlockZero/blob/master/newone/x.asm

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: The code I was talking about in my linked answer is `_mm_set_ps(v[1], v[1], v[0], v[0])` and the Godbolt link.  Change those numbers to anything you want for an arbitrary shuffle and see what the compiler does.  (`shufps` with some constant, if no special-case shorter instruction exists.)

Comment: @PeterCordes but it is C while we see assembly tag

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: yes, it's a method for using a C compiler to answer this question and any like it.  C compilers emit asm which you can look at, and this is a way to give them input that shows what element you want where.

Comment: @PeterCordes it's `imm8`.  So it should be done in nasm preprocessor. open it.really

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: You're assuming that the answer should be a NASM macro like `_MM_SHUFFLE` that you use with `shufps` or `pshufd`?  But some shuffles can be done with other special-case instructions like `unpckhps`, `movhlps`, or whatever.  This is why using a C compiler is nice.  If you want to write a general-case answer with a NASM macro, it would fit almost as well on the other question.  Or if you want to write a self-answered Q&A about how to do any shuffle, that could work, too.  This question isn't a good fit for that because it's about one specific shuffle.

Comment: @PeterCordes so you just admitted that what you posted is nothing like answer. someone can go with `00010011b` only if he know `imm8` format there.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: I was never suggesting that the linked answer directly explains how to write args for `pshufd`. The linked answer tells you how to ask a computer instead of other humans for the answer to this.  Writing the immediate in hex or binary is just a matter of translating the number the compiler spits out.  (Or looking up how pshufd works in the manual...)

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин That makes no sense.  Most of the asm in my answers *is* better (or not worse) than MSVC's asm output.  When compilers already do a good job, like for trivial / boring question such as this, we can just look at their output.  But regardless, there is a duplicates: [How to reverse an \_\_m128 type variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20051746) even takes the trouble to explain the details of how `_MM_SHUFFLE` encodes the constant for shufps, making it easy to port to asm by hand even without using a compiler.  And it's a shuffle that produces the desired low 2 elements.